# Unexplained apple mach o linker error

Tags: ios, xcode

i am working on an app that i actually downloaded and trying to get it to run. 
link here
http://mousebirdconsulting.blogspot.com/2013/12/whirlyglobe-22.html 
I followed all the instructions to the T, included my headers, checked my linked library, build phase, framework path all that. However after configuring the program in a manner i assumed to right…out of no where i get hit with 90-95 errors.
I have read many questions on this same topic and followed the instructions best i code, making sure my quatzcore.framework is present but to no avail.
Would like if someone could look at this and see which framework is missing or the reason why It is throng those errors. Since i believe all the framework and files are there.
Thank You

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGBitmapContextCreate", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataRetWidth:height:roundUp:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataScaleWidth:height:border:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGColorGetComponents", referenced from:
      -[UIColor(Stuff) asRGBAColor] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIColor+Stuff.o)
      -[UIColor(Stuff) asVec4] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIColor+Stuff.o)
  "_CGColorGetNumberOfComponents", referenced from:
      -[UIColor(Stuff) asRGBAColor] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIColor+Stuff.o)
      -[UIColor(Stuff) asVec4] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIColor+Stuff.o)
  "_CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      +[UIImage(Stuff) imageWithRawData:width:height:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataRetWidth:height:roundUp:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataScaleWidth:height:border:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGColorSpaceRelease", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      +[UIImage(Stuff) imageWithRawData:width:height:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataRetWidth:height:roundUp:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataScaleWidth:height:border:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGContextAddPath", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
  "_CGContextDrawImage", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataRetWidth:height:roundUp:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataScaleWidth:height:border:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[TextureAtlas createTexture:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(TextureAtlas.o)
  "_CGContextFillRect", referenced from:
      -[MaplyAnimationTestTileSource imageForTile:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyAnimationTestTileSource.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
  "_CGContextRelease", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataRetWidth:height:roundUp:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataScaleWidth:height:border:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGContextScaleCTM", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
  "_CGContextSetFillColorWithColor", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
  "_CGContextSetLineJoin", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
  "_CGContextSetLineWidth", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
  "_CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
  "_CGContextSetTextDrawingMode", referenced from:
      -[MaplyAnimationTestTileSource imageForTile:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyAnimationTestTileSource.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
  "_CGContextStrokePath", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
  "_CGContextTranslateCTM", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
  "_CGDataProviderCreateWithData", referenced from:
      +[UIImage(Stuff) imageWithRawData:width:height:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGDataProviderRelease", referenced from:
      +[UIImage(Stuff) imageWithRawData:width:height:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGImageCreate", referenced from:
      +[UIImage(Stuff) imageWithRawData:width:height:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGImageGetHeight", referenced from:
      +[WhirlyKitLoadedImage LoadedImageWithUIImage:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LoadedTile.o)
      +[WhirlyKitLoadedImage LoadedImageWithNSDataAsPNGorJPG:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LoadedTile.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataRetWidth:height:roundUp:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGImageGetWidth", referenced from:
      +[WhirlyKitLoadedImage LoadedImageWithUIImage:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LoadedTile.o)
      +[WhirlyKitLoadedImage LoadedImageWithNSDataAsPNGorJPG:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LoadedTile.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataRetWidth:height:roundUp:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGImageRelease", referenced from:
      +[UIImage(Stuff) imageWithRawData:width:height:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGPathRelease", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
  "_CGRectZero", referenced from:
      -[TestViewController makeSelectionView:] in TestViewController.o
  "_NSFontAttributeName", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager addString:changes:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelRenderer renderWithFonts] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager addString:changes:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelRenderer renderWithFonts] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
  "_NSForegroundColorAttributeName", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager addString:changes:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelRenderer renderWithFonts] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager addString:changes:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelRenderer renderWithFonts] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CADisplayLink", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(EAGLView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAEAGLLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(EAGLView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIApplication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.o
      objc-class-ref in AFURLConnectionOperation.o
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(EAGLView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIBarButtonItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIColor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in ConfigViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in StartupViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyAnimationTestTileSource.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyViewController.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyBaseViewController.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIDevice", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AFHTTPClient.o
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIFont", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyAnimationTestTileSource.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AFImageRequestOperation.o
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyImageTile.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(Texture.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyBaseInteractionLayer.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LoadedTile.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIImageView", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_UIImageView_$__AFNetworking in UIImageView+AFNetworking.o
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_UIImageView_$_AFNetworking in UIImageView+AFNetworking.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UILabel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UINavigationController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPanGestureRecognizer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyPanDelegate.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(PanDelegateFixed.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPinchGestureRecognizer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(WhirlyGlobeViewController.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyPinchDelegate.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(PinchDelegateFixed.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPopoverController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIResponder", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIRotationGestureRecognizer", referenced from:
```

---

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGBitmapContextCreate", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataRetWidth:height:roundUp:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataScaleWidth:height:border:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGColorGetComponents", referenced from:
      -[UIColor(Stuff) asRGBAColor] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIColor+Stuff.o)
      -[UIColor(Stuff) asVec4] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIColor+Stuff.o)
  "_CGColorGetNumberOfComponents", referenced from:
      -[UIColor(Stuff) asRGBAColor] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIColor+Stuff.o)
      -[UIColor(Stuff) asVec4] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIColor+Stuff.o)
  "_CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      +[UIImage(Stuff) imageWithRawData:width:height:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataRetWidth:height:roundUp:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataScaleWidth:height:border:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGColorSpaceRelease", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      +[UIImage(Stuff) imageWithRawData:width:height:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataRetWidth:height:roundUp:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataScaleWidth:height:border:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGContextAddPath", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
  "_CGContextDrawImage", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataRetWidth:height:roundUp:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataScaleWidth:height:border:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[TextureAtlas createTexture:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(TextureAtlas.o)
  "_CGContextFillRect", referenced from:
      -[MaplyAnimationTestTileSource imageForTile:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyAnimationTestTileSource.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
  "_CGContextRelease", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataRetWidth:height:roundUp:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataScaleWidth:height:border:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGContextScaleCTM", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
  "_CGContextSetFillColorWithColor", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
  "_CGContextSetLineJoin", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
  "_CGContextSetLineWidth", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
  "_CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
  "_CGContextSetTextDrawingMode", referenced from:
      -[MaplyAnimationTestTileSource imageForTile:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyAnimationTestTileSource.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
  "_CGContextStrokePath", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
  "_CGContextTranslateCTM", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
  "_CGDataProviderCreateWithData", referenced from:
      +[UIImage(Stuff) imageWithRawData:width:height:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGDataProviderRelease", referenced from:
      +[UIImage(Stuff) imageWithRawData:width:height:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGImageCreate", referenced from:
      +[UIImage(Stuff) imageWithRawData:width:height:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGImageGetHeight", referenced from:
      +[WhirlyKitLoadedImage LoadedImageWithUIImage:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LoadedTile.o)
      +[WhirlyKitLoadedImage LoadedImageWithNSDataAsPNGorJPG:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LoadedTile.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataRetWidth:height:roundUp:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGImageGetWidth", referenced from:
      +[WhirlyKitLoadedImage LoadedImageWithUIImage:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LoadedTile.o)
      +[WhirlyKitLoadedImage LoadedImageWithNSDataAsPNGorJPG:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LoadedTile.o)
      -[UIImage(Stuff) rawDataRetWidth:height:roundUp:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGImageRelease", referenced from:
      +[UIImage(Stuff) imageWithRawData:width:height:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
  "_CGPathRelease", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager renderGlyph:font:texSize:glyphSize:offset:textureOffset:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
  "_CGRectZero", referenced from:
      -[TestViewController makeSelectionView:] in TestViewController.o
  "_NSFontAttributeName", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager addString:changes:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelRenderer renderWithFonts] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager addString:changes:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelRenderer renderWithFonts] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
  "_NSForegroundColorAttributeName", referenced from:
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager addString:changes:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelRenderer renderWithFonts] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
      -[WhirlyKitFontTextureManager addString:changes:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelInfo renderToImage:powOfTwo:retSize:texOrg:texDest:useAttributedString:] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
      -[WhirlyKitLabelRenderer renderWithFonts] in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CADisplayLink", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(EAGLView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAEAGLLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(EAGLView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIApplication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.o
      objc-class-ref in AFURLConnectionOperation.o
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(EAGLView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIBarButtonItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIColor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in ConfigViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in StartupViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyAnimationTestTileSource.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyViewController.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyBaseViewController.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIDevice", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AFHTTPClient.o
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIFont", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyAnimationTestTileSource.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(FontTextureManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LabelRenderer.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AFImageRequestOperation.o
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyImageTile.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(Texture.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyBaseInteractionLayer.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(LoadedTile.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(UIImage+Stuff.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIImageView", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_UIImageView_$__AFNetworking in UIImageView+AFNetworking.o
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_UIImageView_$_AFNetworking in UIImageView+AFNetworking.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UILabel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UINavigationController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPanGestureRecognizer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyPanDelegate.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(PanDelegateFixed.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPinchGestureRecognizer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(WhirlyGlobeViewController.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(MaplyPinchDelegate.o)
      objc-class-ref in WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent(PinchDelegateFixed.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPopoverController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIResponder", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIRotationGestureRecognizer", referenced from:
```

Comment: Can you show the command-line produced by Xcode when you build? That will tell us what frameworks it actually attempted to link against.

Comment: `Undefined symbols for architecture i386` means you're probably building for your Mac, rather than the iOS simulator.

Comment: Which version of xcode you are using? Make sure it is not the beta version.

Comment: @Irfan Xcode 4.5.2 not beta

Comment: @Ant It is for the IOS Simulator 6.0

Comment: @user3215538 xcode 4.5.2 is not stable version(I also faced unusual errors and crashes with this xcode) stable version is 4.6.3.

Comment: @user1118321 Added some more of the log (let me know if that was what you wanted to see) Also i see WhirlyGlobeComponent being mentioned a lot but. I DO have it in my program

Comment: @Irfan i See, you think this could be the cause of this errors? (btw have you ever used whirlyglobe)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `Core graphics` framework.Check this image how to add frameworks [image]

Comment: Well i definitely needed that one, I'm down to 36 errors from 90. how could you tell that this one was missing. Also I already had core location and core text inn.

Comment: `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGBitmapContextCreate", referenced from` This line tells that app is not able to find `Core Graphics` framework.`CGBitmapContextCreate` is a function which belongs to `Core Graphics` framework.

Comment: Noted, but If you look at the second bunch of errors it's still saying this even if i have added the core framework as you advised

Comment: Which is the `SDK` you are using?? Is it ios 6?

Comment: Can you check whether u have added `UIKit.framework` also is it marked as required instead of optional.

Comment: added it, again it reduced my errors, asking for CLASS_$_CADisplayLin. Also How do i use -v to see invocation?

Comment: Add `Quatrtzcore.framework` .If u again havve error . Please post the Error list.

Comment: That actually solved it, I knew that the program needed quartz, but It was appearing on the left under my project, therefore i thought it was in the project even it was not in the link library window

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues and it turned out that by having other linker flags in Build Settings but having it empty was causing my problem. Deleted other linker flags entirely and the issue went away.